# When are purrr::partial()-ized functions identical?

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following code and I can't figure out why these functions are different and where they differ:

```r
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}

add1 <- purrr::partial(add, x = 1)
add2 <- purrr::partial(add, x = 1)

identical(add1, add2)
#> [1] FALSE
```

I compared their attributes, bodies and formals as well as their arguments, they are all equal (apparently). I also set the `.env` argument in `purrr::partial()` to `rlang::empty_env()` but it did not help.

```r
str(add1)
#> function (...)  
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "purrr_function_partial" "function"
#>  - attr(*, "body")= language ~(function (x, y)  { ...
#>   ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#>  - attr(*, "fn")= symbol add
str(add2)
#> function (...)  
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "purrr_function_partial" "function"
#>  - attr(*, "body")= language ~(function (x, y)  { ...
#>   ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#>  - attr(*, "fn")= symbol add
purrr::map2(attributes(add1), attributes(add2), identical)
#> $class
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $body
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $fn
#> [1] TRUE
purrr::map2(body(add1), body(add2), identical)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] TRUE

identical(args(add1), args(add2))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(formals(add1), formals(add2))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions don’t have identical environments:

```r
identical(environment(add1), environment(add2))
#> [1] FALSE
identical(add1, add2, ignore.environment = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I’m not sure how two environments would be considered identical:

```r
e1 <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
e2 <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
identical(e1, e2)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>